# source code of the HTML5 version of Angry birds visible?

Tags: html

Today I read that Rovio released Angry birds for Chrome i.e HTML5 compatible. Does it mean that anyone can see the source code of the HTML5 version of the game now?

Comment: it means they can see the client code, which is not likely all of what is necessary to run the game.

Comment: Actually, the game requests to store stuff locally, so I'm guessing that it's supposed to be possible to run offline. According to a tweet by @rem, it exceeds the limit for local storage, however, so nothing is actually stored. I haven't verified this myself though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it's not very readable as it looks to be generated from a Java input, probably via GWT.

The levels are stored as JSON – here's the level 2 file:

```
{
  "camera": [
    {
      "bottom": -51.69,
      "id": "Slingshot",
      "left": -28.397,
      "right": 47.013,
      "top": -51.69,
      "x": 28.621,
      "y": -13.985
    },
    {
      "bottom": -49.048,
      "id": "Castle",
      "left": 12.344,
      "right": 82.582,
      "top": -49.048,
      "x": 66.776,
      "y": -13.929
    }
  ],
  "counts": {
    "birds": 5,
    "blocks": 27
  },
  "id": "pack1/Level57.lua",
  "scoreEagle": 29000,
  "scoreGold": 60000,
  "scoreSilver": 47000,
  "theme": "BACKGROUND_BLUE_GRASS",
  "world": {
    "bird_1": {
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "BIRD_RED",
      "x": 9.93,
      "y": -4.328
    },
    "bird_2": {
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "BIRD_RED",
      "x": 7.489,
      "y": -4.339
    },
    "bird_3": {
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "BIRD_RED",
      "x": 5.417,
      "y": -4.249
    },
    "bird_4": {
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "BIRD_RED",
      "x": 3.42,
      "y": -4.339
    },
    "bird_5": {
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "BIRD_RED",
      "x": 0,
      "y": -1.035
    },
    "block_1": {
      "angle": 90.027,
      "id": "STONE_BLOCK_4X1",
      "x": 61.498,
      "y": -7.314
    },
    "block_10": {
      "angle": 180,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 74.143,
      "y": -0.157
    },
    "block_11": {
      "angle": 180,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 83.499,
      "y": -0.107
    },
    "block_12": {
      "angle": 180,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 92.925,
      "y": -0.058
    },
    "block_13": {
      "angle": 0,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 7.156,
      "y": 1.484
    },
    "block_14": {
      "angle": 135,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 111.252,
      "y": -18.195
    },
    "block_15": {
      "angle": 24.537,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_5X5",
      "x": 3.616,
      "y": -0.22
    },
    "block_16": {
      "angle": 45,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_5X5",
      "x": 11.912,
      "y": -0.041
    },
    "block_17": {
      "angle": 45,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_5X5",
      "x": 103.199,
      "y": -0.037
    },
    "block_18": {
      "angle": 45,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_5X5",
      "x": 106.374,
      "y": -3.514
    },
    "block_19": {
      "angle": 45,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_5X5",
      "x": 109.7,
      "y": -0.188
    },
    "block_2": {
      "angle": 89.999,
      "id": "STONE_BLOCK_4X1",
      "x": 68.165,
      "y": -7.317
    },
    "block_20": {
      "angle": 359.713,
      "id": "PIG_BASIC_SMALL",
      "x": 85.85,
      "y": -15.34
    },
    "block_21": {
      "angle": 2.262,
      "id": "PIG_BASIC_SMALL",
      "x": 75.084,
      "y": -11.419
    },
    "block_22": {
      "angle": 7.16,
      "id": "PIG_BASIC_SMALL",
      "x": 68.143,
      "y": -11.427
    },
    "block_23": {
      "angle": 0.153,
      "id": "PIG_BASIC_SMALL",
      "x": 61.475,
      "y": -11.411
    },
    "block_24": {
      "angle": 179.984,
      "id": "WOOD_BLOCK_4X1",
      "x": 85.911,
      "y": -13.755
    },
    "block_25": {
      "angle": 180.065,
      "id": "WOOD_BLOCK_4X1",
      "x": 75.051,
      "y": -9.834
    },
    "block_26": {
      "angle": 180.172,
      "id": "WOOD_BLOCK_4X1",
      "x": 68.284,
      "y": -9.842
    },
    "block_27": {
      "angle": 0.112,
      "id": "WOOD_BLOCK_4X1",
      "x": 61.463,
      "y": -9.83
    },
    "block_3": {
      "angle": 90.017,
      "id": "STONE_BLOCK_4X1",
      "x": 74.983,
      "y": -7.316
    },
    "block_4": {
      "angle": 270,
      "id": "STONE_BLOCK_8X1",
      "x": 85.892,
      "y": -9.272
    },
    "block_5": {
      "angle": 359.999,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_32X2",
      "x": 75.877,
      "y": -4.433
    },
    "block_6": {
      "angle": 225.001,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 98.165,
      "y": -5.15
    },
    "block_7": {
      "angle": 225.001,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 104.615,
      "y": -11.599
    },
    "block_8": {
      "angle": 90,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 64.836,
      "y": -0.135
    },
    "block_9": {
      "angle": 135,
      "id": "TERRAIN_TEXTURED_HILLS_10X10",
      "x": 60.034,
      "y": 1.675
    }
  }
}
```

This means that you could potentially inject your own levels by intercepting the requests.

Comment: Yes, it's GWT: `function angrybirds(){var O='',vb='" for "gwt:onLoadErrorFn"',tb='" for "gwt:onPropertyErrorFn"'`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it is heavily obfuscated, see small part of code below:

```
function d3(){this.b=new Date}
function MK(){this.o=EU.d.Nc()}
function TE(b,c){b.i.k=c;b.f=4}
function PU(b,c,d){b.f=c;b.g=d}
function YF(b){b.f=6;b.b=false}
function YH(b){b.f=6;b.b=false}
function iG(b){b.f=7;b.b=false}
```

Answer (score 1):

They use the google PlayN framework for the HTML5 port.

See https://developers.google.com/playn/

It means you can see the HTML5 code, but it will not be very useful since it's compiled with GWT and not very understandable.